# What does this syntax on in the Android Java code mean?

Tags: java

Can anybody explain the following codes to me? It is [from the Android source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java?av=f).

The first line looks to me is to initialize an integer array, but what about those codes enclosed in braces? I mean are those codes syntax correct since the braces part
seems to be tangling?

```
    // high priority first
    mPriorityList = new int[mNetworksDefined];
    {
        int insertionPoint = mNetworksDefined-1;
        int currentLowest = 0;
        int nextLowest = 0;
        while (insertionPoint > -1) {
            for (NetworkAttributes na : mNetAttributes) {
                if (na == null) continue;
                if (na.mPriority < currentLowest) continue;
                if (na.mPriority > currentLowest) {
                    if (na.mPriority < nextLowest || nextLowest == 0) {
                        nextLowest = na.mPriority;
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                mPriorityList[insertionPoint--] = na.mType;
            }
            currentLowest = nextLowest;
            nextLowest = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean the { at line 3? It's perfectly fine, it's a block. Think about it as a if(true) { ... }

Comment: The outer block at line 3 is to say that the variables `insertionPoint`,  currentLowest` and `nextLowest` are no longer used after the closing `}`. The block with the `new[]` could have been placed in a separate initialisation method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah those code blocks are absolutely fine. They are viable syntax. Rather they are useful.

What happens there is, the code is just shifted to an unnamed-block, to provide them a block scope. So, any variables defined inside that block won't be visible outside.

```
int[] a = new int[10];
{
    int x = 10;
    a[0] = x;
    System.out.println(x);
}

System.out.println(x);  // Error. x not visible here.
```

So, those `braces` just creates a `local block scope`, that's it. Nothing more special in them. Though, you won't feel the magic of those blocks in the above code.

This way of coding is generally used to `minimize` the scope of your `local variables`, which is absolutely a good idea, specially when, the `variables` created inside that block won't be used anywhere else.

So, if used without those `braces`, those variables will just `hang` around, waiting for the `garbage collector` to free them up, at the same time, enjoying the `trip` towards the end of `current scope`, that might be a very long `method`.